# SetSizeHints to a frame loaded by wxXmlResource

Tags: wxwidgets

Right now I'm using wxWidgets msw 3.0.5 on Windows 7 and the xrc file was created with wxFormBuilder 3.10.1

Normally I use something like this to avoid my wxframe be resized smaller than my child controls:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame( NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("Sometitle") )
{
wxBoxSizer* frameSizer = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );
wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY );
// ..
frameSizer->Add( panel, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0 );       
SetSizerAndFit( frameSizer );
Centre();
}
```

But, when I'm use xrc file to load my frame I using like this:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
// used in App::OnInit()
// wxXmlResource::Get()->InitAllHandlers();
// wxXmlResource::Get()->Load( wxT("some.xrc" ) );
wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame( this, NULL, wxT("MyFrame") );
// ...
Fit(); // this resize my frame to show my child controls as expected (like SetSizerAndFit does )
SetMinClientSize(GetSize()); // is this the right way?
Centre();
}
```

**Fit()** resize my frame same as **SetSizerAndFit**, but if don't use **SetMinClientSize** my frame can be horrible resize shriking and hiden my controls. So my questions are:

1. Is there a feature that I'm missing in wxFormBuilder to avoid resize less the frame child controls?
2. Using **SetMinClientSize** is the right way?
3. Is there are any other ways in xrc file to have the same effect like **SetSizerAndFit**?
   Thanks.

Note: this happens also in my linux wxwidgets library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are unfortunately confusing, but `SetSizerAndFit()` calls `SetSizer()` and `wxSizer::SetSizeHints()`, and not `wxWindow::Fit()` as might be expected. So to have exactly the same behaviour as in the first case you need to call `GetSizer()->SetSizeHints(this)` in your frame code.

And, FWIW, `wxSizer::SetSizeHints()` does something sensibly equivalent to

```cpp
wxSize size = GetBestClientSize();
SetMinClientSize(size);
SetClientSize(size);
```

i.e. it sets both the current and min sizes, which is what you presumably want.

Comment: Thanks, it pointed me to the right direction.